# How can I find the radius using the area of a sector and the angle (in radians)of the sector

Tags: geometry

> Given the area of a sector is $50 cm^2$, and that it's angle is $1.2^c$, find its radius.

The raised $c$ after $1.2$ means radians. How can I find the radius. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An area of a sector is given by $A=\frac{1}{2} r^2 \theta$, where $\theta$ is in radians.

One can rearrange this formula to give $r^2=\frac{2A}{\theta}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks , this was really helpful :)